# graph_transforms in tensorflow 1.4 when installing with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow 1.4.0 with pip3. (Windows)

I'm trying to use `cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow` with a retrained Inception V3 graph.

Unfortunately it seems cv2 does not support retrained graphs so I went through [transform graph.pb into one usable by cv2](http://answers.opencv.org/question/175699/readnetfromtensorflow-fails-on-retrained-nn/), but unfortunately I can't find no transform_graph in graph_transforms in tensorflow.

**Should I install tensorflow differently?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to Build it first.

bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph

Note that it will not work if you're using a Opencv version below 3.3.1 and even than my graphs are not very accurate after loading.

Answer to edit:
yes that script has to be build with bazel and is not in your normal download.

Comment: I updated the question (Windows), bazel build unreliable for windows

Comment: I would install a VM and use it with ubuntu or another linux system . I tried hard to use it on windows but it was just painfull .